# How to remove current Event Listener before adding new one

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I remove current EventListener before adding new one to it? I have below code does a simple countdown:

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
function countDown(dateToProcess):void
            {
               myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdownTimer);
               myTimer.start();

                function countdownTimer(e:Event):void
                {
                   //display dateToProcess.getTime() - today.getTime();
                   trace(myTimer.currentCounter);
                }

            }
```

function countDown is called every X seconds and new datetoProcess value will be passed. However, every time when this function is called, a new TimerEvent.TIMER EventListener is added because the code told it to, is there anyway to remove the current Event Listener before adding new one?

I've tried:

```
 if (myTimer.hasEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER))
                        {
                            myTimer.stop();
                            myTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);

                            trace("remove");
                        }
```

but doesn't seem to be working, it is still adding event Listener, I used trace(myTimer.currentcounter) and output like:
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
Anyone can help with this one please?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you adding 2 event listeners to this single Timer (countdown & countdownTimer functions)? Don't nest functions inside each other, then you'll see the logic a bit better too.

Comment: I just want one event listener to do the count down every time, not adding new one every time when function called. sorry for confusion.

Comment: You can limit the repeat of timer with second parameter: `var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);` and then in its function you would removeEventListener. But still, un-nest the functions.

Comment: but this will stop the counter down timer, so the counter will be updated when next time the function is called instead of every second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what you're after for, but here's one shot using the same Timer:

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,0);

function countDown(dateToProcess):void{
    myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdownTimer);
    myTimer.start();
}

function countdownTimer(e:TimerEvent):void{
    myTimer.stop();
    myTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdownTimer);
    trace(myTimer.currentCount);
}
```

Or:

```
function countDown(dateToProcess):void{
    if(myTimer.hasEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER)){
        myTimer.stop();
        myTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdownTimer);
    }
    myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdownTimer);
    myTimer.start();
}

function countdownTimer(e:TimerEvent):void{
    trace(myTimer.currentCount);
}
```

So it works as you thought it would, you probably just had something in wrong place?

Comment: I've tried both method above and got the same results as my original one. What i'm trying to do here is, when function countDown is called, a single even listener to handle the event, not adding new one. In results, if I trace myTimer.currentCount, I'd expect output like: 1,2,3,4... but now the output is 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4... (depends on how frequent the function is called). Correct me if I got concept wrong but this looks like the function is keep adding new event listener without kill the previous one?

Comment: Hmm, I might need some coffee as I'm still not understanding the question haha! My first example will run the timer once always when you call the function, and second one will stop & continue the timer when calling the function. So in both cases output is 1,2,3,4...

Comment: I add below line to your first example: trace (myTimer.hasEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER)); the output shows True, shouldn't be False? this is right after myTimer.removeEventListener()

Comment: Traces `false` to me. Double check that you don't have any of those old event listeners of yours set.